# Combining multiple templates before render using requireJs & BackboneJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to implement the idea of multiple templates per-view in BackboneJs using requireJs and the requiteJs text plugin.

Here is my view code - you can see i have passed in two templates in my define() of witch gets passed through successfully.

```
define(['Backbone', 'text!Templates/BlogIndex.html', 'text!Templates/Elements/Blog/List.html'], function(Backbone, Template, ElementList){

var BlogPostIndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        var $template = $(Template);

        $template.prepend(ElementList);

        this.template = _.template($template.html());

    },

    render: function (Template) {
        this.$el.html(this.template({posts : this.collection}));
        return this;
    },

    add: function() {

    }

});

return BlogPostIndexView;  });
```

You can see i am trying to combine the second template into the html of the first template. This works but unfortunately when i render then i get this....

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
<div id="blog-post-wrapper">
    <h1>texting views</h1>
</div>

<ul>
    <% _.each(posts, function(post){ %>
        <li><%= post.title %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Besides the list is not evaluated, its position is ok or should it be after 'h1'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm missing closing tag for the outer-wrapper, but lets suppose it should be after closing 'ul' tag and your templates looks as follows:

container.html

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="blog-post-wrapper">
        <h1>texting views</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

list.html

```
<ul>
    <% _.each(posts, function(post){ %>
        <li><%= post.title %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

code:

```
define([..."container.html", "list.html"...], function (...container, list...) { 
...
initialize: function () {
    // container:
    // no need to compile 'container' if there are no variables..

    // list:
    this.listTemplate = _.template(list);
}
...
render: function () {
    var $container = $(container);
    $container.append(this.listTemplate({...})); 
    this.$el.html($container);
}
```

BTW: check this !text alternative https://github.com/tbranyen/lodash-template-loader

Comment: This is the same logic i used in initialise

Comment: could you please print what is the output of $template.html() in initialise function?

Comment: The logic is not the same I think.. in your case you will get content inside 'ul' tag wrapped in double quotes after $template.prepend(ElementList); call.. and that's why it is not evaluated. In my case, you are appending evaluated list..

Comment: I just used Mustache insead